# Running Total Over Repeating Interval in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL.  Data all exists in a single table named `tracks`.

Results Needed as an OR statement:

1. Need the date value of day 1, the date value of day 7, and the count of records for each instance where the number of events that occurred in a 7 day range exceeded 4 grouped by UserID and Dept;
2. Need the date value of day 1, the date value of day 30, and the count of records for each instance where the number of events that occurred in a 30 day range exceeded 6 grouped by UserID and Dept.

This query will be applied to a full year of sporadically scheduled events.

Each record in the example data below represents 1 event.

```
UserID  Event Date  Dept
User1   1/1/2013    A
User1   1/2/2013    A
User1   1/3/2013    A
User1   1/10/2013   A
User1   1/11/2013   A
User1   1/12/2013   A
User1   1/13/2013   A
User1   1/14/2013   A
User2   1/21/2013   B
User2   1/22/2013   B 
User2   1/23/2013   B
User2   1/24/2013   B
User2   1/25/2013   B
User2   1/27/2013   B
User2   1/28/2013   B
User2   4/1/2013    B
```

Result set for the above example should resemble:

```
UserID  Dept   Day1         Day7        Day30       7DayEventCount   30DayEventCount
User1   A      1/10/2013    1/16/2013   2/8/2013    5                5
User1   A      1/1/2013     1/7/2013    1/30/2013   3                15
User1   A      1/2/2013     1/8/2013    1/31/2013   2                14
User1   A      1/3/2013     1/9/2013    2/1/2013    1                13
User1   A      1/4/2013     1/10/2013   2/2/2013    1                12
User1   A      1/5/2013     1/11/2013   2/3/2013    2                11
...
User2   B      1/21/2013    1/27/2013   2/19/2013   6                7
User2   B      1/22/2013    1/28/2013   2/20/2013   6                6
User2   B      1/23/2013    1/29/2013   2/21/2013   5                5
```

Comment: Why is `1/16/2013` Day7 for User1? Your example data doesn't even contain `1/16/2013` for User1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, It appears to be just 7 days after `1/10/2013`.  No query difficulty there, just adding dates.

Comment: The range is irregardless of if an event took place. Every date of the year will have a 7-day and a 30-day range associated. I only want to return the date ranges that meet the event count criteria.

Comment: I'll ignore the use of irregardless.. but why does the `30DayEventCount` for user1 have 8 items?  In that 30 days, there was only 5 events, the same 5 that happened the first week.

Comment: that's a typo. Day1 should = 1/1/2013. Fixed now.

Comment: user2 has a second record b/c there are two date ranges, w/in either a 7-day or 30-day range, where the event count criteria are met.

Comment: added more example result set records to clarify. still incomplete but i think it provides ample info.

Comment: So, then I was right.  Every event per user has a record and 7 and 30 day queries are built off of its event date. Correct?

Comment: Would a single user in a department ever have more than one event in a day?

Comment: it's possible that more than one event might occur by user and by dept in a day. the last record that should be returned chronologically in example has day1 = 1/23/2013. this is the last day either the 7 or 30 day criteria were met.

Comment: let me know if i hit the mark or not.

Comment: syntax error. can't spot it. [Error Code: 923, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: resolved above syntax issue - can't start alias with a number. now looking at:[Error Code: 904, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00904: "E"."eventdate": invalid identifier

Comment: That is probably having a problem with `between e.eventdate and e.eventdate + 7`